# Text put into a field yields strange characters

Tags: javascript, html, razor

I have a JavaScript function into which I put some text thus

```
@{
   var price = @HttpUtility.UrlDecode(Request.QueryString["MaxBudget"]);
   <script type="text/javascript">
      PopulateFormInput('SearchMaxBudget', '@price', 'modal-search-budget-box');
   </script>
}
```

Now, MaxBudget is '£100-£199' but for some reason when I execute this piece of code I get this in the text box.

[image]

I've checked in the debugger and the value passed to PopulateFormInput is '£100-£199' and passing this value in another place statically (i.e. passing the hard coded text '£100-£199') works fine.  Why is this failing?

Thanks,

Sachin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the solution, for anyone who is interested

```
@{
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                        PopulateFormInput('SearchMaxBudget', getParameterByName('MaxBudget'), 'modal-search-budget-box');

                        function getParameterByName(name) {
                            name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\\]");
                            var regexS = "[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)";
                            var regex = new RegExp(regexS);
                            var results = regex.exec(window.location.search);
                            if (results == null)
                                return "";
                            else
                                return decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
                        }
                    </script>
                }
```